# C# LINQ join - use range variable in secondary join

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to use some linq magic to query over two different data sets to compare an inner property on one data set to see if that value is greater than a property in the other data set. I've generalized the class layouts and removed some properties to hopefully make it clearer.

```
public class Contract
{
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
    public IList<Invoice> InvoiceList { get; set; }

    public class Invoice
    {
        public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentDueAmount { get; set; }
    }
}

public class PaymentRequest
{
    public IList<ContractList> Contracts { get; set; }
    public class ContractList
    {       
        public string ContractId { get; set; }  
        public IList<InvoiceList> Invoices { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceList
    {          
        public decimal CurrentDueAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know the following LINQ statement doesn't work but its the general idea on what I'm trying to achieve.

```
from validContract in validContracts
join contract in paymentRequest.Contracts
on validContract.ContractId equals contract.ContractId

from validInvoice in validContract.InvoiceList
join invoice in contract.Invoices
on validInvoice.InvoiceNumber equals invoice.InvoiceNumber

where invoice.CurrentDueAmount > validInvoice.CurrentDueAmount
select "Invoice Number: " + invoice.InvoiceNumber + ", Current Due >= " + validInvoice.CurrentDueAmount;
```

I get an error trying to use the range variable "contract" in the second join statement. 
[image]

I'd like to be able to do the comparison on the objects currentDueAmounts. Any ideas / refactoring, method extractions, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the two sets before joining them like this

```
var query =
    from valid in (
         from contract in validContracts
         from invoice in contract.InvoiceList
         select new { contract, invoice }
    )
    join request in (
        from contract in paymentRequest.Contracts
        from invoice in contract.Invoices
        select new { contract, invoice }
    )
    on new { valid.contract.ContractId, valid.invoice.InvoiceNumber }
    equals new { request.contract.ContractId, request.invoice.InvoiceNumber }
    where request.invoice.CurrentDueAmount > valid.invoice.CurrentDueAmount
    select "Invoice Number: " + request.invoice.InvoiceNumber + ", Current Due >= " + valid.invoice.CurrentDueAmount;
```

Comment: you are the man Ivan! I wasn't sure if my problem description was going to be clear enough to understand but you nailed it. Much appreciated!